# Computing the harmonic mean of an image collection in the Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, average

How can I compute the harmonic instead of arithmetic mean for a series of images in Google Earth Engine? There is a build-in function to compute the arithmetic mean and median, but there is no harmonic/geometric mean available. I tried to build my own function by making use of the reduce function, but with this I did not succeed. Any ideas/examples on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable as follows:

```
// a random point on the map
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([-106.95381215107625, 39.46780712207983]);
// Make some constant images and put them together in a image collection
var list = ee.List([1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,9,9]);
var imageCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list.map(function(integer){
  return ee.Image.constant(integer).toInt();
}));

// Calculate the harmonic mean based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean
var n = imageCol.size(); // number of observations (19)
var harmonicMean = imageCol.map(function(image){
  // Note that function image.pow() cannot handle 0 values
  return image.pow(-1);
}).sum().divide(n).pow(-1);
print('harmonic mean image collection', 
        harmonicMean.reduceRegion('first', point, 1000).get('constant'));

// Calculate the harmonic mean based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean
    // All data points should be possitive
var geometricMean = imageCol.product().pow(ee.Number(1).divide(n));
print('geometric mean image collection', 
      geometricMean.reduceRegion('first', point, 1000).get('constant'));
```

According to Wikipedia, I checked how to calculate the [harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) and [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) mean. And according to [this site](http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/geometric-mean/), the outcomes coincide. [Link to code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/76fa97265ac69f134c58df308d1661ca)